# How to upload image in Mysql database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I got trouble uploading image and saving records in Mysql database using PHP, can somebody help me?

**Code:**

```
<?php
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 300);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 300);
?>
<html>
  <body>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      </br>
      <input type="text" name="dbname"/>
      <input type="file" name="dbimage"/>
      <br> <br>
      <input type="submit" name"submit" value"Upload"/>
    </form>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

      if(getimage($_FILES['dbimage']['tmp_name']) == FALSE) {
        echo "Please select an image";
      } else {
        $dbimage = addcslashes($_FILES['dbimage']['tmp_name']);
        $dbname = addcslashes($_FILES['dbimage']['dbname']);
        $dbimage = file_get_contents($image);
        $dbimage = base64_encode($dbimage);
        saveimage($dbname, $dbimage);
      }

      function saveimage() {
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
        mysql_select_db("db_test", $con);
        $qry = "insert into table1 (dname,dpic) values ('$dbname','$dbimage')";
        $result = mysql_query($qry, $con);
        if ($result){
          echo "Image uploaded.";
        } else {
          echo " Image not uploaded.";
        }
      }
    }?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your "trouble"? What isn't working? What errors are you getting? (Have you turned on error reporting?)

Comment: there is no error, but the records dont save

Comment: Then you most likely haven't turned on error reporting, turn on error reporting (Place this at the top of your code: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);` ) and see what it says.

Comment: <?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);
 ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout',300);
 ini_set('default_socket_timeout',300);
?>  I pasted here, but I dont have any error

Answer (score 0):

You have to give to the function saveimage() the variables $dbname and $dbimage... Neathertheless please use PDO...

Answer (score 0):

You have missed parameters in function saveimage(). It should be like this: 
function saveimage($dbname,$dbimage)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you forgot to pass the params to your function

```
function saveimage($dbname,$dbimage){...}
```

Try to declare your function outside of your condition.